# Clion jumps instead of inserting tab or removing spaces

Tags: clion

I'm having a problem with a Clions indention when I use a function with parameters that continue over multiple lines. For example:

```
example = example_function(param1, param2->param2_2 * param3->param3_2 - param4, TEST_MACRO);
```

If I know add a new line in front of `param3->param4_2` and `TEST_MACRO` I get:

```
example = example_function(param1, param2->param2_2 * 
                       param3->param3_2 - param4, 
    TEST_MACRO);
```

It looks differently for me than here since I use a tab size of 8. My problem is that if I try to delete a tab in front of `param3->param4_2` it works once but the second time all tabs infront are deleted. Also if I try to add a tab infront of TEST_MACRO the cursor instead jumps in front of the first parameter.

I couldn't find anything in the settings and on google and don't know how this feature is called and how it can be turned off. It's driving me crazy. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you please write here which indentation do you wanna get?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As in this example, I would like to delete two tabs in front of `param3->param3_2` and align `TEST_MACRO` with the line above. Actually I would prefer though that it's possible to delete tabs all the way until at the beginning of the line and to be able to add tabs in front instead of jumping somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, it works by other way .Any "magic" that comes from IDE comes in accordance with language formatting rules. Please, select the code style that is close to your estetic. Or castomise the presets (Google Code Style, LLVM Code Style and etc.) New line inside the expression of parameter will never looks good. Sorry.
BUT! You can switching off "Smart Enter" (Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys) .

Comment: Thanks. I also noticed that if I go back once before I press tab, I can indent the line as wanted. Sometimes that also works with deleting.